# Java - NullPointerException for Enum.values() in WAR archive

Tags: java, servlets, enums, nullpointerexception

I've got an Enum class that stores the name and some relevant numbers for 10 different materials. 
In my HTML page I want to select one material via a drop down. Therefore I iterate over them via JSTL. I used to have a scriplet for that but I replaced it now. This is my code:

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session.getAttribute("materialArray") == null) {
            session.setAttribute("materialArray", Material.values());
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/input.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

JSP-Page:

```
{...}
    <h2>
        <fmt:message key="input.label.material" />
    </h2>
    <select name="s_material" id="s_material">
        <c:set var="MaterialEnum" value="${materialArray}" />
        <c:forEach items="${MaterialEnum}" var="material">
            <option value="${material}"><c:out
                    value="${material.description}"></c:out></option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
{...}
```

**Problem**: When I click 'Run project on server' in eclipse and visit the URL in Chrome it works fine.
But when I export the project to a WAR file and deploy it on a server (same tomcat version, different machine) the drop down doesn't fill and I get a NullPointerException for `Material.values()`. Also when I look at it in the eclipse intern browser, the material drop down menu isn't filled. (I used `System.out.println()` in `doGet()` to check if it does anything, it only prints the materials when accessing the page via Chrome. In internal browser it simply prints nothing.)

**Why?** Is there a way to bypass these enum-methods `.values()` and `.valueOf()` (which I use later to process the selected value from the drop down)? **Are there differences in when `doGet()` is called?**

(The scriplet I used before worked in both environments.)